# Способ определения наличия фигуры

Tags: c#, алгоритм, графика, библиотеки

Есть меняющийся фон и иногда появляющийся,прямоугольник с текстом.
Какие есть способы/алгоритмы определения что прямоугольник появился?

Примечание: прямоугольник неровный (форма не меняется), текст русский (не меняется, один и тот же текст).

У меня один и тот же текст, мне его распознавать вообще не надо. Просто нужно узнать что прямоугольник с текстом появился или его нету.

Comment: Уточните вопрос, как не старался не понял абсолютно ничего.

Comment: вопрос для экстрасенсов же....

Comment: неровный, текст русский xDDD

@nbit - теперь все стало на свои места

Comment: можно вообще то и без текста, думал чем больше информации предоставлю тем больше возможностей опеределить наличие фигуры. @Gorets @AlexWindHope Вы бы флуд сообщения удаляли, вон @Котик_хочет_кушать например уточнил и стер.

Comment: @nbit - фигуры где? Откуда она берется? Что вы о ней знаете? и т.д.

И что вы понимаете под "появился"? То что текст русский, а прямоугольник неровный, конечно, здорово, но никак не та информация которая нужна для получения ответа.

Comment: @nbit - бота для Lineage пишете что-ли? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В библиотеке `CV` под названием [**Aforge.NET**](http://www.aforgenet.com/) есть класс [**ShapeChecker,**](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/shape_checker/) который может вам помочь в достижении вашей цели.

*Также, вероятно, схожий функционал реализован в библиотеке [**Emgu.CV**](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)*

---

**Пример использования и соответствующий код**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Open your image
    string path = "test.png";
    Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);

    // locating objects
    BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();

    blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
    blobCounter.MinHeight = 5;
    blobCounter.MinWidth = 5;

    blobCounter.ProcessImage(image);
    Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();

    // check for rectangles
    SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();

    foreach (var blob in blobs)
    {
        List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blob);
        List<IntPoint> cornerPoints;

        // use the shape checker to extract the corner points
        if (shapeChecker.IsQuadrilateral(edgePoints, out cornerPoints))
        {
            // only do things if the corners form a rectangle
            if (shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(cornerPoints) == PolygonSubType.Rectangle)
            {
                // here i use the graphics class to draw an overlay, but you
                // could also just use the cornerPoints list to calculate your
                // x, y, width, height values.
                List<Point> Points = new List<Point>();
                foreach (var point in cornerPoints)
                {
                    Points.Add(new Point(point.X, point.Y));
                }

                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
                g.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.Red, 5.0f), Points.ToArray());

                image.Save("result.png");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Результаты работы**

[image]

[image]

Comment: чтобы устранить неоднозначность в примере, лучше будет вот так написать

List<System.Drawing.Point> Points = new List<System.Drawing.Point>();